# How does longhorn beef compare to other meats wrt a heart-healthy diet?

Tags: heart-disease

This ranch's marketing blurb at http://www.gentzlonghornbeef.com/nutrition_facts compares longhorn beef to other animal protein sources. I'm specifically interested in how the fat breaks down into Trans/Saturated/Unsaturated. I'm also interested in anything that might be problematic but is not disclosed at that site. Also, I've seen the claim that it's good for Omega-3 fatty acids, at sites such as https://www.simmonscattlecompany.com/grass-fed-beef.

Obviously, they want to present the best case to sell their product, so I'd like to know how factual these claims are, and whether anything important is left out.

EDIT:

I'm particularly interested to see the characteristics of the best possible product, so presumably grass-fed longhorn.

Comment: There is allegedly a study entitled "Nutrient density of beef from texas longhorn cattle" published by somebody at Texas A&M in 1987, or maybe 1997. A billion web sites selling Longhorn beef cite this article but I sure can't find it. Let's just say that given how startling those numbers are and how hard the alleged evidence is to find, you can color me skeptical.

Comment: The correct citation:  Byers, F. M., and G. T. Schelling. "Nutrient Density of Beef From Longhorn Cattle." (1987).

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20080514220812/http://www.tlbaa.org/Resources/research1.html

Comment: @Carey Gregory - interesting. I'm reading that now. The study says they used all grain-finished beef, so I've edited the question because I'm looking for the healthiest option, probably grass-fed.

Comment: @CareyGregory ^^^^ Sorry, I was mobile for the last message and couldn't got the notifier working. :)

Comment: @CareyGregory - Read the summary of the study, which was great, thanks. It reflects the thinking at the time that dietary cholesterol contributes to blood cholesterol. I've been told by my general practitioner and my dietitian that the current thinking is that the contribution is very small.

Comment: Yeah, even vegans can have high cholesterol levels.